# Plotting solved ordinary differential equations over changing constant values

Tags: python, odeint

I am currently working on a set of code that I am using to solve an ordinary differential equation... My code is working, however, I would like to be able to modify it to solve the differential equation for a set of different constant values. This is what I have currently, and if ran works.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(w, x):
    # d1 = omega lambda
    d1 = w
    b2 = 0.0

    # 0.2<c<1.4, 0.20 increments
    c = 0.2  

    q = (1 - d1 - (2*((d1**1.5)/c))) / (2 + (3*(b2)))    

    f = (d1**2) * (1 - d1) * ((1 / d1) + (2 / (c * (d1**0.5))) - ((3 * b2 *    q) / (d1 * (1-d1))))
    return f

#determine domain, x
x = np.linspace(-80, 80, 1000001)

d1 = 10 ** -8

sol = odeint(f, d1, x)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("Omega Lambda")
plt.plot(x, sol, 'r')
plt.show()
```

However, I would like to construct a graph that consists of each line that a set of different values of c would produce... the c's I would like to produce a graph of are:

```
c = 0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4
```

Comment: (1) Make `c` a global variable in the function `f` (`global c`). (2) Run the `sol = ...` and `plt.plot...` lines of your code in a `for` loop by `c`.

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(w, x , b2 , c):
    # d1 = omega lambda
    d1 = w


    # 0.2<c<1.4, 0.20 increments
    #c = 0.2  

    q = (1 - d1 - (2*((d1**1.5)/c))) / (2 + (3*(b2)))    
    f = (d1**2) * (1 - d1) * ((1 / d1) + (2 / (c * (d1**0.5))) - ((3*b2*q)/(d1*1-d1))))
    return f

#determine domain, x
x = np.linspace(-80, 80, 1000001)

d1 = 10 ** -8
b2 = 0.0
c = [  0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4 ]
for i in c:

    sol = odeint(f, d1, x, args = (b2 , i))
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("Omega Lambda")
    plt.plot(x, sol, 'r')
    plt.show()
```